# Convert date in dataframe (R)

Tags: r

I am looking to convert:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 
1     0.00  2014-08-10 
2     1.23  2014-07-01
3     2.33  2014-03-11
4     1.29  2014-02-01
5     3.76  2014-02-21
```

to:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 
1     0.00  Aug 10, 2014 
2     1.23  Jul 7, 2014
3     2.33  Mar 3, 2013
4     1.29  Feb 01, 2014 
5     3.76  Feb 21, 2014
```

in a date frame in R.

Note that there is no comma after them month, and no leading zeros on single-digit dates.

Comment: Sounds great. Do you have a *question*? Is there code you are having problems with?

Comment: Although I provided an answer below, I think you should also read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column in your data frame is already a date, you can use the `format()` function to get what you want. If it is not, convert it before using `as.Date()`.

**Example:**

```
d <- as.Date('2014-08-05')
format(d, '%b %d, %Y')
```

For your data frame:

```
df$Col3 <- format(as.Date(df$Col3), '%b %d, %Y')
```

See [the reference below](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) for more formatting symbols.

---

**Reference:**

- [Quick R: Date Values](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

Comment: Excellent thank you!  Still need to remove leading zero from day, but I'm sure some type of sub or gsub will work.

Comment: Take a look to the full [Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net). I've learned a lot about R there